# Сохранение переменной из адаптера в SharedPreference

Tags: android, android-shared-preferences, recyclerviewadapter

Есть приложение, которое получает данные из сервера и выводит в список `RecyclerView`.
В каждом `item` находится `checkbox` в виде изображения сердечка. При нажатии на это сердечко оно должно менять цвет, но это не главное. Главное - оно должно сохранять свое состояние при следующем запуске приложения с помощью `SharedPreference`. Так как мне сохранить это значение из адаптера и проверять его в `onCreate`?

Активити, в котором выводится список

```
public class CatalogActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private Toolbar toolbar;
private CatalogAdapter catalogAdapter;
private ImageView imageFavorites;
private boolean favorite;
private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_catalog);

    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_catalog);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);


    //sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 2));
    getData();
    
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_toolbar_catalog, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == android.R.id.home)
    //Возврат на предыдущий экран
    {
        int backStackEntryCount = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
        if (backStackEntryCount > 0) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        } else {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        }
        onBackPressed();
    }
    //Переход в активити корзину
    if (id == R.id.menu_basket) {
        startActivity(new Intent(CatalogActivity.this, BasketActivity.class));
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

//Получение данных с сервера
public void getData(){
    NetworkRequest.getRequest()
            .getTestApi()
            .getTestModel()
            .enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<Item>>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<Item>> call, Response<ArrayList<Item>> response) {
                    ArrayList<Item> item = response.body();
                    catalogAdapter = new CatalogAdapter(CatalogActivity.this, item);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(catalogAdapter);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<Item>> call, Throwable t) {
                    Toast.makeText(CatalogActivity.this, "Безуспешно", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
}
```

}

Адаптер

```
public class CatalogAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CatalogAdapter.CatalogViewHolder> {
Context context;
ArrayList<Item> arrayList;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
int id;

public CatalogAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Item> arrayList){
    this.context = context;
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
}
@NonNull
@Override
public CatalogViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
    return new CatalogViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CatalogViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Item item = arrayList.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(item.getTitle());
    holder.text.setText(item.getBrand());
    holder.price.setText(String.valueOf(item.getPrice()));

    Picasso.with(context)
            .load(item.getImageLink())
            .into(holder.imageView);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return arrayList.size();
}

public class CatalogViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageView, imageFavorites;
    TextView title, text, price;
    int id;
    CheckBox checkBox;
    boolean favorite;
    public CatalogViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewItem);
        title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.titleItem);
        text = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textItem);
        price = itemView.findViewById(R.id.priceItem);
        checkBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_favorite_item);

        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (checkBox.isChecked()){
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Добавлено в корзину", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    favorite = true;
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Удалено из корзины", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    favorite = false;
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
}
```

Не могу создать экземпляр класса `SharedPreference` в адаптере. Как организовать логику сохранение состояния?

Answer (score 1):

Ваш адаптер не должен знать о существовании всяких там адаптеров. Он должен уметь **ТОЛЬКО РИСОВАТЬ**. Ваши данные могут попадать откуда угодно, и `RecyclerAdapter` не должен зависеть от источника подачи данных.

Я бы сделал это примерно так:

Допустим мы получаем от сервера ответ в виде списка `List<Items>`. Создаем модельку вроде:

```
class UiItem {
    private final Item item;
    private final boolean isLiked;
    // любые другие поля нужные для отображения в адаптере
    // getters/setters
}
```

Собственно где-нибудт в. `Presenter/ViewModel` мы весь этот список `List<Item>` оборачиваем в список `List<UiItem>`.

```
List<UiItem> mapToUiModel(List<Item> items){
    List<UiItem> uiItems = new ArrayList();
    for(Item item : items){
        uiItems.add(new UiItem(item, sharedPreference.getLiked(item.id)));
    }
    return uiItems;
}
```

И на вход адаптера мы уже передаем список в котором есть лайканые или не лайканые элементы.

Когда вы обрабатываете клик на лайк, вы сохраняете поле `isLiked` в `SharedPreference` по `id` и полностью в вашем `Presenter/ViewModel` прогоняете мапинг и снова обновляете ваш адаптер.

Чтоб не обновлять всякий раз весь адаптер, а менять только измененные элементы используйте [DiffUtils](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/DiffUtil).

Comment: ваш вариант показался мне сложным и запутанным, поэтому я решил иным способом

Comment: Ваше право писать так как вам нужно.

Answer (score -1):

В методе `onBindViewHolder` вызвал методы которые отвечают за сохранение - `save` и за загрузку - `load`

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CatalogViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Item item = arrayList.get(position);

    holder.title.setText(item.getTitle());
    holder.text.setText(item.getBrand());
    holder.price.setText(String.valueOf(item.getPrice()));

    Picasso.with(context)
            .load(item.getImageLink())
            .into(holder.imageView);

    holder.favorites.setChecked(load(String.valueOf(position)));
    holder.favorites.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            save(String.valueOf(position), true);
        }
    });
}
```

Сами методы (в том же классе - CatalogAdapter)

```
 public void save(String key, boolean value){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("Values", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}

public boolean load(String key){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("Values", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key, false);
}
```